# Application not Installed in Android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I developed an application, this application has 2 versions. when Install new version Application on old version.it shows Application Not Installed.

my manifest :

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/smsbox_2_logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:largeHeap="true"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Main_Page"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.addSMS_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_new_sms"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.ShowSMS_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_show_sms__page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.MySMS_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_my_sms__page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.Fav_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_fav__page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.login_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_login__page"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.register_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register__page"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.category_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register__page"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.category_select_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_register__page"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.about_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_about__page"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.setting_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_setting__page"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.tellfa.smsbox.activities.splash_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_splash__page">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".activities.connectus_Page"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_connectus__page"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Build.Gradle code :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tellfa.smsbox"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 10
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),         'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

how to fix it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32910041/android-when-i-try-to-install-my-signed-app-it-says-app-not-installed/32919015#32919015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably used a different keystore file, you need to uninstall the app and re-install it

Comment: If i use the previous keystore version, fix it ?

Comment: yeah its advised to use one keystore file for you app and keep it safe and write down its password so you wont forget it for future updates for your application :)

Answer (score 2):

Just uninstall old Application and then install new version

Comment: tnx but i know this way. I do not want uninstall and install

Answer (score 0):

Set minimum and target Sdk versions in mainfest

Answer (score 0):

the keystore should be same for two versions. in this case you have to un-install previous version and reinstall new version will fix the issue. or use the same keystore